# Progress codebase analysis using Moose

Tags: code-analysis, progress-4gl, legacy-code, moose-technology

Has anyone used [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org/about) to deal with a large legacy Progress ABL/4GL codebase, and if yes, what are the caveats, experiences, lessons learned you can share about this?

Answer (score 1):

From building a Delphi parser for Moose I know that it takes quite a lot of effort to get your FAMIX model complete. I'd recommend to make your feedback cycle as short as possible.
From the [progress grammar](http://www.joanju.com/dist/docs/tree_spec.html) I'd say the system looks a bit more complicated than Delphi. Focus on the real & perceived problems and take shortcuts to find solutions for them. 
So you might want to delay writing a parser in Smalltalk, and just start using the pro parse stuff to generate a MSE file containing the interesting bits.

If the system is really large you might have to be careful not to run out of memory currently.

You are aware of the [humane assessment site](http://www.humane-assessment.com/)? The blog provides lots of examples and things to do/don't.

It really is an environment for developers, extremely powerful and having still a lot of rough edges. The [mailing list](http://forum.world.st/Moose-f1310756.html) is very helpful

When dealing with legacy systems, there are a few things I do before starting Moose, to get a feeling for the system. I run a [duplication detector](http://www.inf.usi.ch/phd/wettel/dude.html) and zip the individual table dumps (that works well on progress files). Large files that compress extremely well are interesting discussion topics :)